# How to implement a text widget with my own flutter scaling factor

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am implementing an application in flutter. And as the title says, I want to set my own textScaleFactor on all widgets of this type. Is there any way to overwrite this value in the main.dart? Or how could I set it in a custom class that inherits the type text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanking Levi Stepanek for the answer, I found the way to apply the text scale factor in all parts of the app with the following code:

```
    MaterialApp(
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
             return MediaQuery(
             data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.2),
             child: child,);},
          ..
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text scale factor by changing the `textScaleFactor` argument.

```dart
Text(
  "your text here",
  textScaleFactor: 1.0,
);
```

Change 1.0 to whatever you want the scale factor to be.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to put this value in main.dart so that all text widgets have this value?